# Books on Non-Standard Analysis from a model theory standpoint

Tags: logic, model-theory, book-recommendation, nonstandard-analysis

After studying ultraproducts in my model theory course, I have become rather fascinated by the nonstandard numbers. I asked my professor about books on the hyperreals and hyperintegers, but he couldn't come up with one. 
Is there a superior book on the subject? I am looking for one I can use to teach myself nonstandard analysis. I understand logic/model theory notation and theory best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My personal favorite is Goldblatt's book [Lectures on the hyperreals](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387984643). But Kanovei's book [Nonstandard analysis, axiomatically](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540222439) should also be kept in mind: Kanovei presents an entire set theory around nonstandard-ness, and is the natural conceptual development after Goldblatt for someone interested in set-theoretic foundations.